# Readiness probe failed: Get http://*.*.*.*:8080/***/healthCheck: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

The GCP Error reporting Dashboard is showing following error for one of our production cluster ,could you please help me with it is this an issue or information about the pod is not ready to take traffic at that movement

---

Readiness probe failed: Get http://*.*.*.*:8080/***healthCheck: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

---

Comment: Can you show some yaml?

Comment: I would start seeing in the GCP Cloud Logging for a couple of days @deHaar which YAML you want to have a look on ?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a yaml problem, but the deployment or whatever contains that probe would be nice to see.